# Beer-A-Day (Free Online) Calendars

Tags: breweries, specialty-beers

I'm looking for free online beer-a-day calendars highlighting a different beer every day. Anything available for the United States, Germany, Bavaria, for example?  Ideally the calendars also include a web feed for subscription. Any insight welcome.  Cheers. Prost.

Disclaimer: As examples I've put together a free online beer-a-day calendar for [Austria](http://at365.herokuapp.com) - [(Feed)](http://at365.herokuapp.com/feed) and for [Belgium](http://be365.herokuapp.com) - [(Feed)](http://be365.herokuapp.com/feed).  All example code and data public domain (that is, free, open source).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of anything, but if you already have code to do one and just need data you may be able to leverage [BreweryDB's](http://www.brewerydb.com) API and scrape beers that way.  It's a pretty extensive database.

Comment: Thanks - For my own online beer-a-day calendars I use the [beer.db](http://openbeer.github.io) - that offers public domain (open, free) beer n brewery data. Cheers. Prost.

Answer (score 1):

You could use flickr Beer Nation group.
https://www.flickr.com/groups/beer_nation/

Then subscribe to a feed.
https://www.flickr.com/get_the_most.gne#rss

This way you will get pictures of beer every day. If you want to use their photos for your own calendar you are allowed to do this according to flickr's rules. A quick Google of github.com, lists some open source repositories you can use.

Comment: Thanks. Great idea and source. Any idea or chance on how to find out what beer is in the photo? (e.g. any meta data e.g. tags etc.)  Cheers. Prost.